Cannot find and uninstall an installed package on MacOS
So I created a .pkg file by MAUI and apparently it was for App Store only and I should not have installed it. The problem is now I am stuck with that package on my Mac and I cannot install it from TestFlight, and I cannot find the files anywhere. I already follow the steps here: Uninstall packages in Mac OS X but I cannot find the files.

pkgutil --pkgs confirms com.mycompany.appname is still in the system.

pkgutil --pkg-info com.mycompany.appname says it should be at /Applications but it is not:


root@LukesMac /Applications % pkgutil --pkg-info com.mycompany.appname
package-id: com.mycompany.appname
version: 2.0.0
volume: /
location: Applications
install-time: 1715099769


pkgutil --files com.mycompany.appname list all the files that the package should have. Problem is I tried to search for it in Finder with both ._AppName.app and AppName.app (with hidden files enabled), none show up:

root@LukesMac /Applications % pkgutil --files com.mycompany.appname
._AppName.app
AppName.app
AppName.app/._Contents
AppName.app/Contents
(and the full content of all the files in my app)


I even try using ls -A to search for the files but none of them show up:

root@LukesMac /Applications % ls /Applications/AppName.app/
ls: /Applications/AppName.app/: No such file or directory
root@LukesMac /Applications % ls /Applications/._AppName.app/
ls: /Applications/._AppName.app/: No such file or directory
root@LukesMac /Applications % ls ~/Applications/._AppName.app/
ls: /Users/lukevo/Applications/._AppName.app/: No such file or directory
root@LukesMac /Applications % ls ~/Applications/AppName.app/ 
ls: /Users/lukevo/Applications/AppName.app/: No such file or directory
root@LukesMac /Applications % cd /Applications
root@LukesMac /Applications % ls -A
(no file that I need)
root@LukesMac /Applications % cd ~/Applications 
root@LukesMac Applications % ls -A
(no file that I need)

I have also tried using Spotlight Search. I also deleted the original .pck file as well as the compiled file by MAUI (bin and obj folders).
What should I do? I am a Windows user so please excuse any obvious mistake I may have made.

Look for it in /System/Volumes/Data/Applications -- see "What's /System/Volumes/Data?"

@GordonDavisson still didn't find it anywhere in there. However could be because I just want to solve it and run --forget. Maybe Mac cleaned it up (hopefully).

@GordonDavisson I just installed the package again to make sure. The package exists and there is no no file in /System/Volumes/Data/Applications as well.
